# Upload a video using asp.net MVC WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to upload a video file using asp.net mvc . I am sending the file as postbody. How can this be retrieved later from the server using webservice. I have seen this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38970/Implementing-HTTP-File-Upload-with-ASP-NET-MVC) . Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613346/unable-to-upload-video-file-to-asp-net-mvc-3) helped me to understand it more. But I m not sure how to fetch post body.
  But no sure how this works. How to do his properly in .net c#

Answer (score 0):

In order for the file to be available later, you need to save it somewhere during the upload - either to a database or a folder on the server.  Then, your web service needs to know how to retrieve it from that location.